# Does upgrading window 8 to window 8.1 will affect Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, upgrade, windows-8

i have a window 8.1 update to my laptop.But am afraid that after updating window 8 it will affect the grub menu and i wont able to boot into Ubuntu..is it safe to upgrade to window 8.1 ??

Answer (score 0):

It will overwrite the grub bootloader as you fear, but with a livecd you can run a `sudo update-grub` command on the disk and it will resolve it

Comment: If pre-installed Windows 8 with UEFI, Windows then likes to set itself first in UEFI boot menu, so it always boots as default. If you have been able to select ubuntu entry in UEFI you may be able to reset Ubuntu as first. Or use one time boot key like f12, but varies by vendor or select in UEFI menu.